# Style errors with API level 23

Tags: android

As soon as I update my `build.grade` file to API level 23, I get errors that I cannot locate, and cannot fix them. However, these same errors do not show up with 22 or 21. The error that shows up is:

`Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined`, and for some reason, it highlights the `colors.xml` file. There are no instances of `titleTextColor` in my entire project. When I do a project wide (cmd + shift + f) search, the only instances of `titleTextColor` show up in generated build files. What's going on here, and how can I fix this?

[Edit] `build.grade` file

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'play'

repositories {
    //ViewPagerIndicator AAR packaged
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven'
    }
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    publishingConfigs {

    }

    signingConfigs {

        basicRelease {

        }

        advancedRelease {

        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('publish/debug.keystore')
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

        basic {
            applicationId "com.basic"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }

        advanced {
            applicationId "com.advanced"
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0.1"
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

        release {

        }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError true

    htmlReport true

    checkAllWarnings true
    warningsAsErrors true
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v13'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.1.Final'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
    //https://github.com/weddingparty/AndroidFloatLabel
    compile ':float-label:1.2.1.0@aar'

    //Forked from https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs
    compile 'eu.inmite.android.lib:android-styled-dialogs:1.2.0'

    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp')
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'info.metadude.android:typed-preferences:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-ndk-agent:5.0.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile('com.segment.analytics.android:analytics-core:3.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:showcaseview:5.1.1@aar'
    compile files('libs/appsflyer-2.3.1.16.jar')
    debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.madge:madge:1.1.1'
    debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.scalpel:scalpel:1.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    }
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like in one of your dependencies "`titleTextColor`" attribute could already be defined.

For example, this popular square library has an open ticket:

https://github.com/square/android-times-square/issues/226

So remove the culprit library or in-case if you need the library, you will need to revert back to API 22.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's very interesting. Would there be a more efficient way to narrow down the library rather than going through one by one and resyncing the gradle build?

Comment: If you have all the dependencies in place..you can easily check the culprit..If colors.xml is failing, there has to be two conflicting sources.. Just use the "Scroll to source" option in studio

Comment: When I scroll to source... it points to the first line, `<resources>` in my local `colors.xml` file

Comment: I found the dependency to use NavigationView is the problem, `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`, when i try to use it gradle stop building the project **Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined**. So how i suppose to solve this if i need to use NavigationView widget and i dont have access to dependencies internal source. @user2511882